# Error in implementing String comparison in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++14

My string `s` contains 0's and 1's. Why are the values of `Ascore` and `Bscore` zero, and not incrementing given the conditions below?

```
int main()
{
        long long int n;
        string s;
        cin>>n;   // 3
        cin.ignore();
        long long int siz = 2*n, Ascore = 0, Bscore = 0;
        cin>>s; // 101011
        for(int i = 0; i < siz; i++ )
        {

            if((i%2 == 0) && (s[i] == 1))
                Ascore++;
            if((i%2 == 1) && (s[i] == 1))
                Bscore++;
            if(abs(Ascore-Bscore) == 2)
                cout<<i+1<<"\n";
            if((i % 2 == siz-1) && (Ascore == Bscore))
                cout<<i+1<<"\n";


        }

}
```

Comment: `s[i] == 1` --> `s[i] == '1'` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `string` is composed of `char`s, so you need to compare against `char` literals, not `int`s. e.g.

```
s[i] == '1'
```

instead of

```
s[i] == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a integer 1 instead of character '1'

```cpp
  for(int i = 0; i < siz; i++ )
        {

            if((i%2 == 0) && (s[i] == '1'))
                Ascore++;
            if((i%2 == 1) && (s[i] == '1'))
                Bscore++;
            if(abs(Ascore-Bscore) == 2)
                cout<<i+1<<"\n";
            if((i % 2 == siz-1) && (Ascore == Bscore))
                cout<<i+1<<"\n";


        }
```